# Running asynchronous jobs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on rails 3.1.10. Ruby 1.9.2.

I want to trigger a method after creation of every `order`(I am using spree). I want to do it in such a way that the rendering is not stalled and application is not slowed down.

I know I can use `delayed_job`, but I have found it to be unreliable. In past I have seen jobs not getting added to the delayed_job queue.

So, I have decided to use `SQS` by AWS. I want to push the order details to SQS as soon as order gets created. What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but "not being added to the queue" seems weird, since the queue is just a table--I've yet to see total failure like that.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Maybe job gets added to queue but doesn't get executed. I have no way of finding why the job execution failed with delayed job. Or do I?
I have also seen deadlocks occurring with delayed_jobs. I don't have a definitive proof, but when I added delayed jobs I started seeing deadlocks and when I removed it then deadlocks also disappered.

Comment: Jobs should be instrumented the same was as your code, and those logs should be available. I'm not saying you're not having issues, I'm just saying I've never seen anything that wasn't fixable. In fairness, I haven't used it in over a year now, either.